# how to check for duplicates in a char array c

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C and how would I check the duplicates of a 1D char array

for example

```
#define MAX_SIZE 60
Char canvas[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
for(int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
   //How do i check if there is a duplicate in that array?
}
```

How do I iterate through to check for duplicates, like do i have to use double for loops and do sizeOf(canavas)/SOMETHING here?

Comment: Char is user-defined type?

Comment: Char is an array of characters that i will be using to make a simple canvas using characters. and yes it is user-defined type.

Comment: Double loop is the way.

Comment: but thats the issue tho @Mawg I tried i kept getting out-of-bounds, I'm sure how to get the size of it. its a char, so its one byte it should be not an issue if u i did in the second loop for i < MAX_SIZE right ?

Comment: How would you do this on paper?

Comment: Make an array, a[], of  integers with all values set to 0. Iterate over each char in canvas and set `a[canvas[i]] += 1;`. Then check if  `a[canvas[i]]` is greater than 1. If it is, you have a dupe.

Comment: I'm not sure how this works

Comment: What information do you want to find?  Whether or not there is a duplicate (it doesn't matter which character or how many times it is repeated)?  Which is the first duplicated value? How many different characters each had at least one duplicate?  Which character is duplicated most often?  How many duplicates there were for each duplicated value?  Which positions hold the duplicates for each duplicated character?  Do you need to leave the data unaltered?

Answer (score 4):

My solution, using a function:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool mem_hasduplicates(const char arr[], size_t len)
{
    assert(arr != NULL);
    if (len == 0) 
        return false;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len - 1; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < len; ++j) { 
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) { 
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    const char canvas[] = "zcxabca";
    printf("%x\n", mem_hasduplicates(canvas, sizeof(canvas)/sizeof(canvas[0])));


    const char other_canvas[] = "abcfsd";
    printf("%x\n", mem_hasduplicates(other_canvas, sizeof(other_canvas)/sizeof(other_canvas[0])));
}
```

Live version available at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/SJubI2kq7).

@edit Or we can "just" create a histogram from all the numbers as @selbie suggested, although this got me complicated fast:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct histogram_value_s {
    char value;
    unsigned int count;
};

struct histogram_s {
    struct histogram_value_s *v;
    size_t len;
};


#define HISTOGRAM_INIT()  {0}

void histogram_fini(struct histogram_s *t)
{
    t->len = 0;
    free(t->v);
}

static int histogram_sort_by_value_qsort_cb(const void *a0, const void *b0)
{
    const struct histogram_value_s *a = a0;
    const struct histogram_value_s *b = b0;
    assert(a != NULL);
    assert(b != NULL);
    return a->value - b->value;
}

void histogram_sort_by_value(struct histogram_s *t)
{
    qsort(t->v, t->len, sizeof(*t->v), histogram_sort_by_value_qsort_cb);
}

static int histogram_sort_by_count_qsort_cb(const void *a0, const void *b0)
{
    const struct histogram_value_s *a = a0;
    const struct histogram_value_s *b = b0;
    assert(a != NULL);
    assert(b != NULL);
    return a->count - b->count;
}

void histogram_sort_by_count(struct histogram_s *t)
{
    qsort(t->v, t->len, sizeof(*t->v), histogram_sort_by_count_qsort_cb);
}


int histogram_getValue_2(const struct histogram_s *t, char value, size_t *idx, unsigned int *ret0)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t->len; ++i) {
        if (t->v[i].value == value) {
            if (ret0) {
                *ret0 = t->v[i].count;
            }
            if (idx) {
                *idx = i;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void histogram_printlns_generic(const struct histogram_s *t, const char fmt[])
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t->len; ++i) {
        printf(fmt, t->v[i].value, t->v[i].count);
    }
}

int histogram_add(struct histogram_s *t, char value)
{
    size_t idx;
    if (histogram_getValue_2(t, value, &idx, NULL) == 0) {
        if (t->v[idx].count == UINT_MAX) {
            goto ERR;
        }
        ++t->v[idx].count;
    } else {
        void *tmp;

        tmp = realloc(t->v, (t->len + 1) * sizeof(*t->v));
        if (tmp == NULL) goto ERR;
        t->v = tmp;

        t->v[t->len] = (struct histogram_value_s){
            .value = value,
            .count = 1,
        };
        ++t->len;
    }

    return 0;
ERR:
    return -1;
}

bool histogram_has_any_count_greater_then_2(const struct histogram_s *t)
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < t->len; ++i) {
        if (t->v[i].count >= 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------- */

int histogram_create_from_mem(struct histogram_s *ret0, const char arr[], size_t len)
{
    assert(ret0 != NULL);
    assert(arr != NULL);

    struct histogram_s ret = HISTOGRAM_INIT();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {

        const char to_add = arr[i];

        if (histogram_add(&ret, to_add) < 0) {
            goto ERR;
        }
    }

    *ret0 = ret;
    return 0;
ERR:
    histogram_fini(&ret);
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    const char canvas[] = "abc";

    struct histogram_s h;
    int ret;
    ret = histogram_create_from_mem(&h, canvas, sizeof(canvas)/sizeof(canvas[0]));
    if (ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mem_createhistogram error!\n");
        return -1;
    }


    printf("'%s' %s duplicates\n",
        canvas,
        histogram_has_any_count_greater_then_2(&h)
            ? "has"
            : "does not have"
    );

    histogram_fini(&h);
}
```

Live version [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1G2TnyqQ).

@edit Or we can sort the array, and check if any two adjacent bytes are the same!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int cmp_chars(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}

int main() {
    char canvas[] = "abca";

    qsort(canvas, sizeof(canvas) - 1, sizeof(canvas[0]), cmp_chars);

    bool duplicate_found = false;
    for (char *p = canvas; p[1] != '\0'; ++p) {
        if (p[0] == p[1]) {
            duplicate_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("'%s' %s duplicates\n",
        canvas,
        duplicate_found ? "has" : "does not have");
}
```

Live version available at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/ByB7JTycX).

Comment: Nice, but you should rename it to `hasduplicates` instead of `checkduplicates` so that a statement like `if(hasduplicates(arr, len))` makes more sense.

Comment: The OP appears to be coding in C, not C++

Comment: @Mawg What do you mean? All code I've posted here should compile with C99 compatible compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If `Char` is just a typo for `char`, then this becomes relatively simple - set up a second array, indexed by character code, that keeps track of the number of occurrences of each character:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>
...
int charCount[SCHAR_MAX+1] = {0}; // We're only going to worry about non-negative
                                  // character codes (i.e., standard ASCII)
                                  // [0..127]
...
/**
 * This assumes that canvas is *not* a 0-terminated string, and that
 * every element of the array is meaningful.  If that's not the case,
 * then loop on the length of the string instead of MAX_SIZE.
 */
for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++ )
{
  if ( canvas[i] >= 0 && canvas[i] <= SCHAR_MAX )
  {
    charCount[canvas[i]]++;  // index into charCount by the value of canvas[i]
  }
}
```

Then you can walk through the `charCount` array and print all the character values that occurred more than once:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= SCHAR_MAX; i++ )
{
  if ( charCount[i] > 1 )
  {
    /**
     * If the character value is a printable character (punctuation, alpha,
     * digit), print the character surrounded by single quotes - otherwise,
     * print the character code as a decimal integer.
     */
    printf( isprint( i ) ? "'%c': %d\n" : "%d: %d\n", i, charCount[i] );
  }
}
```

What's that `SCHAR_MAX` all about, any why am I yammering about non-negative character codes in the comments?

In C, characters the *basic execution character set* (digits, upper and lowercase letters, common punctuation characters) are guaranteed to have non-negative encodings (i.e., the `[0..127]` range of standard ASCII).  Characters outside of that basic execution character set may have positive or negative values, depending on the implementation.  Thus, the range of `char` values may be `[-128..127]` on some platforms and `[0..255]` on others.

The `limits.h` header defines constants for various type ranges - for characters, it defines the following constants:

```
UCHAR_MAX - maximum unsigned character value (255 on most platforms)
SCHAR_MIN - minimum signed character value (-128 on most platforms)
SCHAR_MAX - maximum signed character value (127 on most platforms)
CHAR_MIN  - minimum character value, either 0 or SCHAR_MIN depending on platform
CHAR_MAX  - maximum character value, either UCHAR_MAX or SCHAR_MAX depending on value
```

To keep this code simple, I'm only worrying about character codes in the range `[0..127]`; otherwise, I'd have to map negative character codes onto non-negative array indices, and I didn't feel like doing that.

Both this method and the nested loop solution require some tradeoffs.  The nested loop solution trades time for space, while this solution trades space for time.  In this case, the additional space is fixed regardless of how large `canvas` becomes.  In the nested loop case, time will increase with the square of the length of `canvas`.  For short inputs, there's effectively no difference, but if `canvas` gets large enough, you will notice a significant decrease in performance with the nested loop solution.